# AWS Lambda needs to be moved in different Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, subnet

I have a Lambda function that is in VPC-A and Subnet 1A and 2A. I want to move it to Subnet 1b and 2B.

The command below is giving error: aws rds modify-db-subnet-group --db-subnet-group-name "XXXX" --subnet-ids "XXX" "YYY" "ZZZ"

The error is: Some of the subnets to be deleted are currently in use: subnet-ABCD, subnet-WXYZ (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: d636a255-9cfe-4f1c-89de-77ebcb1b9af3)

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `aws rds` to modify a Lambda function.
Try with

```
$ aws lambda update-function-configuration \
--function-name ExampleFunction \
--vpc-config SubnetIds=comma-separated-vpc-subnet-ids,SecurityGroupIds=security-group-ids
```

Doc is available at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html